# how to benchmark an ubuntu webserver using Jmeter and create a test report.?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, benchmark, load-testing, stress-testing, jmeter

I have an ubuntu webserver(LAMP) running a clients website.I have already created a test plan with jmeter, what i would like to know is how would we benchmark  the server with Jmter and create a test report.

Like the maximum number of concurrent users it can handle and maximum number of requests the server could serve with out any issues.

Answer (score 1):

As per [The Load Reports](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65153-the-load-reports) guide, JMeter out-of-the-box [Aggregare Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) Listener will provide following performance metrics:

- **# Samples** - is the number of samples with the same label.
- **Average** -  is the average time of a set of results.
- **Median** - is a number which divides the samples into two equal halves. Half of the samples are smaller than the median, and half are larger. [Some samples may equal the median.] This is a standard statistical measure. The Median is the same as the 50th Percentile.
- **90% Line (90th Percentile)** - meaning 90% of the samples took no more than this time.
- **Min** - is the shortest time for the samples with the same label
- **Max** - is the longest time for the samples with the same label
- **Error %** - is the percent of requests with errors
- **Throughput** - s measured in requests per second/minute/hour. The time unit is chosen so that the displayed rate is at least 1.0. When the throughput is saved to a CSV file, it is expressed in requests/second, i.e. 30.0 requests/minute is saved as 0.5.
- **Kb/sec** - throughput measured in Kilobytes per second. Time is in milliseconds.

You might also use [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/) which provide some more useful graphs and listeners like:

- [Active Threads Over Time](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/)
- [Response Timer Over Time](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime/)
- [Transactions Per Second](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/)

Or alternatively use [JMeter Cloud Plugin](http://blazemeter.com/blazemeters-plug-jmeter) which does all above and more and also has different test runs comparison feature.